# How to I limit the scope of "Find All References" searches in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a C++ project where the build tool creates a whole slew of .i files in a build folder. When I run "Find All References" to a symbol, Visual Studio Code (with the MS Cpp extension) insists on searching this build folder, which is a subfolder of the `workspaceFolder`. It slows down the search and produces nonsense results in an "Other References" pane.

I've tried disabling this behavior by modifying `includePath` and browse.Path to not include that build folder, I've tried using files.Exclude, but nothing seems to work. Is there a correct way to get Find All References to behave properly in such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this writing, this is not yet supported.

This was raised as a feature request in the VS Code Cpptools GitHub repo: [Add ability to limit Find All References to scopes: current file, open files, workspace files #4102](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/4102). The issue ticket is still open. <sup><sub>You can show your support for the issue ticket by giving a thumbs up reaction to the issue. But please *don't* make a "me too" comment. "me too" comments generally come off as annoying to repo maintainers because they clutter up discussion and don't contribute anything of significant value.</sub></sup> Current suggested workarounds include using the `files.exclude` VS Code setting to temporarily exclude folders you don't want results for, or do similarly with a C_Cpp configuration's `browse.path` setting.

This feature-request was also raised more generally to the VS Code GitHub repo: [Find All References scopes #102038](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102038) but that one is closed since VS Code itself does not plan to address it in the foreseeable future.

However, in your very specific case of build artifacts being searched, I would highly recommend just adding the build artifact folder to your workspace's `files.exclude` VS Code setting, or at least the `search.exclude` setting.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found this info by googling "`github vscode issues "find all references" scope`".